# gcc: why does linking fail when rebuilding after changing .c file but not when initially building?

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, ld

I have the following files:

main.c

```
#include "other.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    other();
    return 0;
}
```

other.c

```
#include "other.h"

void other(void) {
    1+1;
}
```

other.h

```
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

void other(void);

#endif
```

and I am using this makefile:

```
OBJ = other.o main.o

main: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(OBJ) -o $@

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c

other.o: other.c
    gcc -c other.c

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) main
```

When I run `make clean && make`, everything compiles and links successfully.

Then, I make a whitespace change to `other.c`.

Now, when I run `make`, I get the following error:

```
gcc other.o main.o -o main
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `other'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Why does linking fail after updating `other.c`?

Note that linking works if I make a whitespace change to `main.c`, or if I again run `make clean`.

UPDATE: In case it's useful, I compared the other.o file in the working case with the other.o file in the broken case; they have a slight difference. I have no idea what would cause this difference, nor how to interpret it. See image: [difference between other.o, working case and broken case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY8en.png)

Comment: Please add output of  `make` during problematic build.

Comment: `make` is great, but not perfect. In multi-source projects, if you change something that changes how something is seen through a header file, or add a variable used in more than a single file, then it is often a good idea to `make clean && make` for the next build. That said, the compiler is probably eliminating `other` as a no-op above when compiling `other.c` resulting in the linker error. Don't use meaningless code (or explicitly use `-O0` to eliminate optimizations).

Comment: @fukanchik, I added more detail regarding the output of make.

@DavidC.Rankin, thanks for the tips. I get the same result using `-O0`; also this was happening with my 'real' project where `other` was actually doing work. 

Regardless, if the solution is just to run `make clean` to resolve this kind of error, that is sort of unsatisfying, but if I guess I can live with it as long as it's not because I'm doing something incorrectly....

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. If you reverse the list of files in `OBJ` (i.e., `OBJ = main.o other.o`, do you still see the same thing?

Comment: @larsks, I get the same result regardless of the order of the object files.

Comment: What version of gcc? On what distribution?

Comment: What does `nm` show for the symbols in all the object files, such as `main.o`, and both the "good" and "bad" `other.o`?

Comment: If you change `other.c`, shouldn't `other.o` be recreated? Why isn't this part of your `make` output?

Comment: See updated post for answer to the two latest questions.
@larsks, I was using gcc version 7.3.0 and ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, although this may not be as relevant now that I have figured out the problem.  
I think I was able to figure this out with the commenters' help - thanks!

Comment: @ThomasB Please post answers as answers, not an edit to your question.

Comment: @melpomene, done. As this is my first time on stackoverflow I did not realize I could answer my own question. :)

Comment: You can even accept your own answer as "the solution", but [you'll have to wait 48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I figured this out. It seems to be happening because of the linter I have in my text editor (Atom version 1.33, linter version 2.2.0, linter-gcc version 0.7.1).

When I update the file other.c in Atom and save, the file `other.o` is also updated via the linter. If I compare the symbols in `other.o`, before it includes `other_function`, but after it includes `_Z14other_functionv`. The updated timestamp on `other.o` also explains why `make` is not running `gcc -c other.c`.

When I make the whitespace change using a different text editor, `make` works correctly.